# How to edit a HTML list in WordPress?

Tags: pages, page-template, html

I'm new to WordPress and what I want to do is to edit the HTML of a specific page in WordPress. For example, a page in my website shows in the source code (in Chrome) a list, that I can see in the normal browser view, but when I get to the dashboard and search for the template the specific page uses, I cannot see the list.

How can I find the specific part of the page that I need to edit, either using WordPress interface or HTML code done by hand.

What I need to do is to modify the HTML page I see on the source code in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

Content in a page can come there in four ways in WordPress:

- **In-page Content:** That's coming from the WordPress' site's page content itself. In this case you have to edit the page in your `/wp-admin`.
- **Page Template:** That's coming from a page template. In this case, you have to get into your theme folder to get the page template what is responsible for that content. You can get the page template name from the page's Quick Edit feature (see the image below), as well as you can get the name of the template if you open up the page in Edit mode.

  [image: Get page template name]
- **Functions' hook:** Any content can be hooked either with a WordPress filter/action, remotely — commonly from the theme's `functions.php` - but it's rare. In that case you have to find that responsible function to edit the content.
- **iFrame:** In some cases the page content's grabbed from any 3rd party site, in that case there an iframe is placed inside the Page's content area, something like: `<iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>`. In that case, you actually can't edit the page content, but can edit/remove the iframe source from the Page.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress isn't just HTML pages you edit. WordPress is a framework built around PHP so a lot of the template files container a mixture of PHP and HTML cut into many parts. You'll need to get familiar with PHP and HTML if you want to successfully (not mess up your theme) edit your files.

You'll need to do some legit research before you jump into it - here's some reading [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), [Example of How Pages Look](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

If you're not familiar with PHP I suggest you look into that first and start off editing a test website (not a live one). Finally if you're not comfortable making PHP changes I suggest you contact a developer.